# Why is this Segmented Prime Sieve so fast?

Tags: c, primes

The idea of a *prime sieve* is fascinating - but it has to be segmented to increase the locality of the code if you want it to be fast.

**Walish's segmented_sieve.cpp** (see below)showed me that it works - fast. It took me some time to understand how the segments are managed. Once my version was working, it was 5% faster than the .cpp. I was a bit disappointed - Walish's cpp seemed more elegant than super-fast.

After switching from `int` to `unsigned` and `(r-1)/2` to `r/2`, my code is now almost **twice as fast**. This is my first Q: **is this a special case?** All the `r`'s are odd, but the compiler probably can't know. Anyway, I changed *all* to unsigned (except main() and argc.

I need this index-to-value translation (`2*i+1`) (or viceversa) all over the place. I think the compactness of my segments shows here, in the inner loop, where the candidates are deleted:

```
segment[r/2] = 0;   THIS VERSION
sieve[j] = false;   WALISH'S
```

This is my second guess: since memory usage is crucial here, I gain speed by leaving out (not just skipping) even numbers.

Plus: My segments start without 2-13 multiples.

Here my commented code:

```
/* Segmented Prime Sieve with pre-sieved pattern
   Segmentation tricks based on Kim Walish's segmented_sieve.cpp, and wikipedia */
/* Counts primes under 1G in 0.4s (2.3GHz i5) (above .cpp: 0.7s) */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>

/* This "inflates" a preprime pattern like "101" to "10.101101101.01" (dot = new zero) */
unsigned grow_pat_by(unsigned p, char *pattern, unsigned patsize) {
    unsigned i;
    /* Multiply by p */
    for (i = 1; i < p; i++)
         memcpy(pattern + i*patsize, pattern, patsize);
    /* Sieve out every p */
    for (i = p/2; i < p*patsize; i += p)
        pattern[i] = 0;
    
    return p * patsize;
}
/* Classic/simple self sieve (odds only), with lower limit for pre-sieved sieves */
void sieve_above(char *sieve, unsigned start, unsigned max) {
    unsigned p, pp; 
    for (p = start; p <= sqrt(max); p += 2)
        if (sieve[p/2]) 
            for (pp = p*p; pp <= max; pp += 2*p) 
                sieve[pp/2] = 0;
}
/* Translates an index in preprimes[] into number in primes[]. Return value could be used to know size/number */
unsigned * gather_primes(char *preprimes, unsigned min, unsigned max, unsigned *primes) {
    unsigned i;
    for (i = min/2; i <= max/2; i++)
        if (preprimes[i]) 
            *primes++ = 2*i+1;    
    return primes;
}
/* A new segment activates higher primes[] into new runners[]
 * In a segment[], the numbers are indexed: num=2*i+1 and i=(num-1)/2, but the "-1" does not matter (odd integers)
 * Unsigned makes it about 20% faster */
void do_segment(unsigned segm_start, unsigned segm_end, unsigned char *segment, unsigned *primes, unsigned *runners, unsigned *irun) {

    /* Do new prime squares fit in this segment? */
    unsigned p;
    while((p = primes[*irun]) > 0 && p*p <= segm_end)
        runners[(*irun)++] = p*p - segm_start; 

    /* Run each runner[i] through and past the end of this segment */
    unsigned segm_size = segm_end - segm_start;
    unsigned i, r;
    for(i = 0; (r = runners[i]) > 0; i++) {
        while (r < segm_size) {
            segment[r/2] = 0;         
            r += 2*primes[i];
         }
        /* Reset for next segment: same pattern, different offsets */ 
        runners[i] = r - segm_size;
    }
}
/* Initialize pattern[], preprimes[], primes[] and allocate runners[]. Prepare segment[] and call do_segment() */
void segmented_sieve(const unsigned MAX) {
    const unsigned SQR = sqrt(MAX);
    unsigned i;

    /* pattern[] is used for preprimes[] and segment[]
     * "101" is "1-(3)-5" i.e. "3" is sieved out. Even numbers are left out. Relation: number value is 2*index + 1 */
    static char pattern[3*5*7*11*13 * 2] = {1, 0, 1};             
    unsigned patsize = 3; 
    /* grow (multiply and sieve) until patsize reaches magical ~30KB*/
    patsize = grow_pat_by( 5, pattern, patsize); 
    patsize = grow_pat_by( 7, pattern, patsize); 
    patsize = grow_pat_by(11, pattern, patsize); 
    patsize = grow_pat_by(13, pattern, patsize); 

    /* preprimes[] shall deliver primes up to ~65K = sqrt(4G) = 32KB phys. (no odds) */
    /* So copy pattern twice (phys. patsize: 15015)*/
    char *preprimes = malloc(256*256/2);                       
    memcpy(preprimes,         pattern, patsize);
    memcpy(preprimes+patsize, pattern, patsize);
    /* Primes 2-13 can be skipped */        
    const unsigned FIRST = 17;   
    sieve_above(preprimes, FIRST, SQR);    

    /* Fill primes[] up to SQR, followed by zeroes. 7000 is enough to hold primes up to 65500 */
    unsigned *primes = calloc(7000, sizeof*primes);            
    gather_primes(preprimes, FIRST, SQR, primes);
    
    free(preprimes);

    /* Optimize: stretch pattern[] by 2 (without sieving) to make segments a bit bigger (30KB) */
    memcpy(pattern + patsize, pattern, patsize);
    patsize *= 2;

    /* The segment is a working copy of pattern[] that should fit into lowest cache 
     * 30030 is a primorial, but the "x2" only slips back in because of "stretching" of the odds-only 15015-pattern 
     * Without stretching, or with a second one, speed goes down (locality/cache) */
    static unsigned char segment[3*5*7*11*13 * 2];

    /* runners[i] has primes[i]'s current offset for do_segment() */
    unsigned *runners = calloc(7000, sizeof*runners);

    /* Segments advance in numbers by 2xpatsize (no odds in pattern)
     * First one has "1" set, but lacks "2,3,5,7,11,13", thus "count" starts at 5. Last segment is simply truncated to MAX */ 
    unsigned count = 5;
    unsigned irun = 0;
    unsigned segm_start, segm_end;
    for (segm_start = 0; segm_start < MAX; segm_start += 2*patsize) {

        /* Fresh pattern for segment */
        memcpy(segment, pattern, patsize);
        
        segm_end = segm_start + 2*patsize;
        if (segm_end > MAX)
            segm_end = MAX;

        do_segment(segm_start, segm_end, segment, primes, runners, &irun);

        /* Count (and possibly print by numbers) the sieved segment */ 
        for(i=0; 2*i+1 < segm_end - segm_start; i++) {
            count += segment[i];
            //if (segment[i]) 
                //printf("%d\n", segm_start + 2*i+1);
        }
    }            
    printf("PI of %d (prime count): %d\n", MAX, count);

    return ;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("No limit given\n");
        return 1;
    }
    unsigned MAX = atoi(argv[1]);
    if (MAX < 100)
        printf("Choose a number above 100, and below 4G. Not: %d\n", MAX);
    segmented_sieve(MAX);
      return 0;
}
```

Here Walish's c++ version; check out his `for(;...<limit; ...++)` loops:

> ```
> <kim.walisch@gmail.com>  /// @brief    This is a simple implementation
> of the segmented sieve of ///           Eratosthenes with a few
> optimizations. It generates the ///           primes below 10^9 in 0.8
> seconds (single-threaded) on an ///           Intel Core i7-6700 3.4
> GHz CPU. /// @license  Public domain.
>
> #include <iostream>
> #include <algorithm>
> #include <cmath>
> #include <vector>
> #include <cstdlib>
> #include <stdint.h>
>
> /// Set your CPU's L1 data cache size (in bytes) here const int64_t
> L1D_CACHE_SIZE = 32768;
>
> /// Generate primes using the segmented sieve of Eratosthenes. ///
> This algorithm uses O(n log log n) operations and O(sqrt(n)) space.
> /// @param limit  Sieve primes <= limit. /// void
> segmented_sieve(int64_t limit) {   int64_t sqrt = (int64_t)
> std::sqrt(limit);   int64_t segment_size = std::max(sqrt,
> L1D_CACHE_SIZE);   int64_t count = (limit < 2) ? 0 : 1;
>
>   // we sieve primes >= 3   int64_t i = 3;   int64_t n = 3;   int64_t
> s = 3;
>
>   std::vector<char> sieve(segment_size);   std::vector<char>
> is_prime(sqrt + 1, true);   std::vector<int64_t> primes;  
> std::vector<int64_t> multiples;
>
>   for (int64_t low = 0; low <= limit; low += segment_size)   {
>     std::fill(sieve.begin(), sieve.end(), true);
>
>     // current segment = [low, high]
>     int64_t high = low + segment_size - 1;
>     high = std::min(high, limit);
>
>     // generate sieving primes using simple sieve of Eratosthenes
>     for (; i * i <= high; i += 2)
>       if (is_prime[i])
>         for (int64_t j = i * i; j <= sqrt; j += i)
>           is_prime[j] = false;
>
>     // initialize sieving primes for segmented sieve
>     for (; s * s <= high; s += 2)
>     {
>       if (is_prime[s])
>       {
>            primes.push_back(s);
>         multiples.push_back(s * s - low);
>       }
>     }
>
>     // sieve the current segment
>     for (std::size_t i = 0; i < primes.size(); i++)
>     {
>       int64_t j = multiples[i];
>       for (int64_t k = primes[i] * 2; j < segment_size; j += k)
>         sieve[j] = false;
>       multiples[i] = j - segment_size;
>     }
>
>     for (; n <= high; n += 2)
>       if (sieve[n - low]) // n is a prime
>         count++;   }
>
>   std::cout << count << " primes found." << std::endl; }
>
> /// Usage: ./segmented_sieve n /// @param n  Sieve the primes up to n.
> /// int main(int argc, char** argv) {   if (argc >= 2)
>     segmented_sieve(std::atoll(argv[1]));   else
>     segmented_sieve(1000000000);
>
>   return 0; }
> ```

I can confirm his 0.8s on a i5-8xxx, with `-O2`. My version needs `-O3` (and `-lm`).

Can I further improve speed and/or design?

If it gets even faster, I will have to change from `unsigned` to `long` for `MAX`. Highest MAX I tested was 3 billion.

So many mathematical stuff to consider - and then the compiler needs help to turn 17 into 8: `10001` -> `1000`

*(oh, so it is just a right shift)*

---

Update: the variables can stay `int` with `segment[r>>1] = 0` (430ms) instead of `[r/2]` (500ms) or even `[(r-1)/2]` (550ms).

With `unsigned r`, both`r>>1`and `r/2` are 410ms. Good enough.

The version above (everybody unsigned, [r/2]) is still fastest: 400-405ms. (I saw 0.400 several times, but never 0.399 (for 1 billion))

Normally these kind of optimizations are frowned upon - but this inner loop over a compact odds-only-segment is not "normal".

---

`unsigned *primes` makes the difference: 402ms. So 90% of above `unsigned`s are not necessary.

Comment: A *high* possibility of what is going on here is just that you aren't actually sorting it - The C compiler discards any variables you aren't using, so all you're going to end up doing is incrementing `count` that many times. If you want to actually see how long it takes to sort lists like that, you need to put it on `-O0`

Comment: You either need to do that, or in some way force the compiler to not optimize specific variables/operations away.

Comment: What's the point of your updates?

Comment: "...you aren't actually sorting it" --- true, these prime numbers come already sorted. Haven't checked it, though.

Comment: @Mast To help you answer my questions. What is the point of your comment?

Comment: Just keeping an eye out. Please keep in mind not to change too much after receiving answers. It's explained [here](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765).

Comment: I did not change the code. It's still full of `unsigned` with no `r>>1`.

Comment: I know, but you asked the point of the comment. Had the edit be a problem we'd have rolled it back already.

Comment: Sivix - What I mean by "you aren't actually sorting it" is that you aren't even processing anything. Most likely, you're just incrementing a variable X amount of times, and printing a constant for the number of primes found.

Comment: Kim's code is meant to illustrate the idea, and IMO does that, is simple, easy to read, and surprisingly fast.  However it is just an illustration, missing a lot of optimizations.  See the slightly out of date [SoE benchmarks](http://ntheory.org/sieves/benchmarks.html) for some timing and code for lots of others.  It looks like the code you're starting with is the "Walisch byte segment" version, which is the slowest listed (again because it is wonderfully illustrating the concept, rather than using convoluted optimizations).

Answer (score 1):

Argument checking - we test for missing argument; we should also fail if there are extra arguments, rather than just ignoring them.  `atoi()` is a poor function to convert strings to integers - in particular, it accepts negative values, it produces a signed value, and it doesn't reject out-of-range values or trailing garbage.  Consider `strtoul()` or `strtoull()` instead.

And after checking, we should both print an error message (to `stderr`, not `stdout`) and exit with a failure status.

Handling of signed and unsigned is poor; my first test gave strange output:

```
./254091 3000000000
PI of -1294967296 (prime count): 144449537
```

That's so easily avoided, it looks like you've taken no care over correctness.

As you've hinted in the description, you might need to change the type used for arithmetic.  But it's scattered all over the code, giving you many places to change.  A better start would be to add a typedef which can be easily changed to work with wider types.

---

Here's a better `main()`:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s LIMIT\n", argv[0]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    char *end;
    unsigned long max = strtoul(argv[1], &end, 0);
    if (*end || max < 100 || max > UINT_MAX) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Choose a number above 100, and below %u. Not: %s\n",
                UINT_MAX, argv[1]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    segmented_sieve((unsigned int)max);
}
```

Comment: You should probably mention the fact that they were using optimization and that optimization probably prevented half of the code from actually getting used.

Comment: Yes, there was a `%d` in `printf()`. Should be: `%u` . This arg test is a last minute feature, mostly to avoid a result of 6 for an input of 10 without a warning. Thank you for the better main()!

Answer (score 0):

Some concerns about preforming the function right, not just fast.

**Slow and ...**

`sqrt(max)`, potentially, is evaluated for each loop.  This give the classic approach an unfair performance assessment.

```
for (p = start; p <= sqrt(max); p += 2)
```

Some compilers will "know" `sqrt(max)` returns the same result each time and so only call `sqrt(max)` once.  This is not something that should be relied on to happen.

```
// Alternative
unsigned end = sqrt(max);
for (p = start; p <= end; p += 2)
```

**... and maybe wrong**

`sqrt()` is not specified to return the *exact* square root for a perfect square.  With a quality implementation, this issue is rare.   Still, better to round up than integer truncate.

```
unsigned end = ceil(sqrt(max));
```

What can be a problem is when conversion of `max` (perhaps it is a 64-bit integer type) incurs rounding converting to `double`, imprecision within the `sqrt()` calculation and truncation when converting the result from `double` to the integer type.

Code could use your own `isqrt()` to avoid that - or use `for (p = start; p <= max/p; p += 2)`.  See next.

**Code risks overflow**

`i * i <= high` risks overflow when `high` is near the max value of the type.  Consider `i*i <= high` can be true, but `(i+2)*(i+2)` on the next iteration overflows.

An alterative that does not overflow when `i > 0`:

```
for (; i <= high/i; i += 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the main difference is visible, when the left over sieve-indices are counted:

**n += 2**

```
    for (; n <= high; n += 2)
        if (sieve[n - low])      // n is a prime
            count++;
```

**i++**

```
   for(i=0; 2*i+1 < segm_end - segm_start; i++) {
       count += segment[i];
```

My segments are double-density, because they are odds-only. Yes, `+= 2` skips evens easily, but wastes cache space.

The `2*i+1` is not complicated enough to loose that advantage. a problem. Making this `i` unsigned does not help.

Here a version with only the necessary `unsigned` and a comment on that `[r>>1]`.

```
void do_segment(int segm_start, int segm_end,                   // real numbers
                char *segment, unsigned *primes, int *runners,  // arrays
                int *irun) {                                    // activated primes/runners

    unsigned p;
    while((p = primes[*irun]) > 0 && p*p <= segm_end)
         runners[(*irun)++] = p*p - segm_start;

    unsigned segm_size = segm_end - segm_start;
    unsigned i, r;
    for(i = 0; (r = runners[i]) > 0; i++) {
        while (r < segm_size) {
            segment[r>>1] = 0;                  // or [r/2] but not [(r-1)/2] (1% slower)           
            r += 2 * primes[i];
         }
        runners[i] = r - segm_size;
    }
}
```